# Multiple projects on GIT

Tags: git, laravel, github, bitbucket

I've installed GIT on Windows some time ago, connected to a Github account repository, on parallel I must work on another project on BitBucket. Now I can't connect GIT to BB, because the account doesn't match.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can setup ssh keys for both github and bitbucket at the same time on windows and work concurrently without any problems.

Comment: ^ Or just import the same SSH key into both github and bitbucket.

Comment: @Devon i wouldn't recommend that. Might make things easier, but from a security perspective that's a bad idea.

Comment: Tongue in cheek: Who cares about security? It's technical stuff we care about here. :-D

Comment: @Sandeesh, how do I do that? On git directory there's more than one ssh folder...

Comment: @Sandeesh what exactly is the security concern?  If someone gets access to your private key directory, it doesn't matter how many different keys you have in there...  Even if Bitbucket or Github were to be hacked and they obtained your public key, it'd be near impossible with modern computers to deconstruct that key into your private key.  That is one of the primary reasons SSH keys are secure.

Comment: @Devon did you even think before replying? SSH keys give complete access to a user's account. It's not about cracking the key, it's about having a key compromised. Using the same key on multiple services would then allow for the user with the key to access all the services using the same key. You just went overboard with your thought process.

Comment: @Sandeesh... that's why you don't give out your private key...  I'm not sure you understand how asymmetric cryptography works.  In github and bitbucket, you would be loading the public key into your user account, not a group account and you never give out your private keys.  Educate yourself: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40050/what-is-the-best-practice-separate-ssh-key-per-host-and-user-vs-one-ssh-key-for.  If you store both keys on the same computer, it doesn't make you any more secure.

Comment: @Devon it's pointless trying to explain to you. The whole point was you recommended using the same key pair on 2 different services. It's not about giving the private key/public key. It's about having your private key compromised leading to the person obtaining the key to have access to multiple services, thanks to using the same key pair.

Comment: @Sandeesh and like I wrote multiple times now, you're suggesting storing two private keys on the same computer which provides no additional protection what-so-ever from keys being compromised.

Comment: @Devon all right i'm done. Go back to your first comment and try to think what i'm trying to convey. Using the same key pair for multiple services would leave u with just 1 private key, which if compromised gives the attacker access to all the services where you've used the same key. Therefore i suggested it would be better to have different ssh keys for both the sites instead of using the same. If you can't get this you're too dense.

Comment: @Sandeesh omg, and how would that key be compromised?  Think through this...  They would get access to your computer and take it off your hard drive.  So why would one key in a folder be at any more risk of being compromised than two?   Hopefully this is just a brief period of ignorance for you calling people dense when clearly you have a lack of experience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144498/discussion-between-sandeesh-and-devon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup ssh keys for both github and bitbucket at the same time on windows and work on each repository with different remotes without any problem.

Here are some resources to help you do that.

https://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/git/windows-git-ssh-authentication-to-github

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html

Or you could setup the remotes using the default web route (https) and provide your login information on each pull or push.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly. I've done an --unset and when I try to commit Git asked me for an account...